# Inverse domain problem

Tags: inverse-function, domain-theory

My task is to find the domain of inverse of : $f(x) = \dfrac{\cos e^x}{1-\cos e^x}$ .

Now, if I am correct the inverse should be : $f^{-1}(x) = \ln\Bigl(\arccos\dfrac {x}{x+1}\Bigr)$ .

If I solve the ln part I get : $\langle -\infty,-1\rangle$

And for the arccos part I get : $\langle -\infty,-1\rangle$ and $\langle -\infty,-1\rangle \cup [ -\frac{1}{2},\infty\rangle $ giving the final result for arccos part:
$ [-\frac{1}{2},\infty\rangle$ .

And the final domain does not make sense cause the final intersection would be an empty set. Could you please help me solve my problem.

Comment: How can this function have an inverse?

Comment: Hint : Find the range of the function by noting that $\cos(e^x)$ can have any value from $-1$ to $1$ (You should get $y\ge -2$)

Answer (score 1):

The function has no global inverse, because it assumes each of its value infinitely many times.

However, we can invert a branch of it, say over an interval of the form $(-\infty,a]$.

We have $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty$. Moreover, writing the function as
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\cos e^x}-1
$$
we can easily compute its derivative as
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{e^x\sin e^x}{(1-\cos e^x)^2}
$$
showing that the function is decreasing on the interval $(-\infty,\log\pi]$. The function has a minimum at $\log\pi$ and
$$
f(\log\pi)=\frac{\cos\pi}{1-\cos\pi}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
Thus we can invert the function over the interval $(-\infty,\log\pi]$ and the domain of the inverse is $[-1/2,\infty)$.

An analytic expression of this inverse can be obtained as follows: write
$$
y=\frac{1}{1-\cos e^x}-1
$$
with $y\ge-1/2$, so
$$
\cos e^x=\frac{y}{y+1}
$$
For $y\ge-1/2$ we have $-1\le y/(y+1)<1$, so we can use the standard branch of the arccosine and
$$
x=\log\arccos\frac{y}{y+1}
$$
so the inverse we found can be expressed as
$$
g(x)=\log\arccos\frac{x}{x+1}
$$

There are other intervals where the function is invertible, for instance $[\log\pi,\log(2\pi))$, $\log(2\pi),\log(3\pi)]$ and so on. Pick your preferred one.